# Angular requirejs tag before HTML tag has 100% height without adding 100% height to css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, requirejs

I felt the requirejs script tag before html tag is weird, I decided to move to head tag. If I move the script tag to the head tag, my page will not be fully 100% height. I have to add 100% height to all elements to keep whole page 100% height. If I keep this script as is, it works fine and the whole page did extend to 100% height.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/assets/js/main" src="/lib/require.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-cloak>
          <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put script tags right before </body> anyway to load crucial content first and then scripts.

Comment: @HenriHietala I tried to but then I have to add 100% height css to every element to keep 100% height. Why it works if I keep the script tag before html tag?

Comment: Can you fill in more details of how you manipulate element heights and what is the wanted outcome?

Comment: @HenriHietala It is an chat application and I want the a div element to be 100% height so the whole page looks like a desktop application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your html is invalid (script tags do not belong before doctype,html tags). As such by having the script tag before the doctype declaration your browser will not recognize your doctype declaration, and instead will <strike>revert to their default</strike> change according to the HTML parser. And in most cases this causes the browser to operate in a "quirks"/backword compatibility mode.  In these modes browsers do not comply fully with the specs (W3C spec for instance).

So you get elements with 100% height. There are other things like how the document is rendered, how certain properties are calculated (clientHeight, clientWidth, etc)

[Quicks and Strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)

[List](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-document-quirks) of the names of the modes according to the WHATWG and a couple notes

[Dectecting mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.compatMode)

[Height calculation in quirks mode](http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-percentage-height-calculation-quirk)

Comment: I think your point is right. But I can't find the place that mentions 100% height. Can you point it out or attach the link here?

Comment: Additionally, if you want an element to have a % height, you **must** define the height of every parent of an element. That is because the browser's rendering engine cannot calculate a percentage height of a child element if it's parent's height is implicit (or not explicitly defined)

Comment: @angelokh, added a link that talks about how the height is calculated in quirks mode.